# SAS Fill In Blanks With Retain Statement

Tags: sas, retain

So I am trying to retain values on SAS but with a condition that includes my ID field. I have the following dataset:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 230 |
| 1 | 450 |
| 1 | . |
| 1 | . |
| 2 | . |
| 2 | . |

I want to retain provided the ID is the same and zero if its a dot, see results below:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 230 |
| 1 | 450 |
| 1 | 450 |
| 1 | 450 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the UPDATE trick.

```
data test;
   infile cards expandtabs;
   input id amount;
   cards;
1   230
1   450
1   .
1   .
2   .
2   .
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data test2;
   update test(obs=0) test;
   by id;
   if first.id and missing(amount) then amount=0;
   output;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: This will carry forward all variables not listed in the BY statement.  Does that apply here?